# Split text to get certain value

Tags: vb.net

How can I split this xml node to get only the number value?

```
<span>All Potatoes: 4</span>
```

Something like this:

```
Dim code as string = "<span>All Potatoes: 4</span>"
Dim splitrsult as string
Splitresult = splitresult("<span>All Potatoes:" & "</span>")
Msgbox(splitresult)
```

I'm newbie in this language, and help would be appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the XML as XML! (not as a simple string)

Use this imports statement

```
Imports System.Xml.Linq
```

Then parse your string in order to get an Xml element and get its value

```
Dim code As String = "<span>All Potatoes: 4</span>"
Dim node = XElement.Parse(code)
Dim result As String = node.Value ' ==> "All Potatoes: 4"
```

Comment: To get only the numeric value, use regex like this : `string numValue = Regex.Match(result, @"\d+").Value`

Answer (score 2):

As another answer mentions, use XML parser to get the value between tags. Once that is done, **if your text definitely has format of** `description : <value>`, the most efficient way would be to split string

```
Dim description As String = node.Value
Dim value As Integer = Integer.Parse(description.Split(": ")(1).Trim())
```

But if you don't guarantee that there will be something after `:`, you can use `Integer.TryParse`. And if there is no guarantee that there is only one `:`, you can take last element of array

```
Dim a() Ad String = description.Split(":")
Dim val As Integer 
If Not Integer.TryParse(a(a.Length - 1), val) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Value is not found")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Value is " & val.ToString())
End If
```

`Regex` is expensive and only needed when you look for patterns within text. If you have structured text, you don't have to use `regex`

Comment: Thank you guys! I learn so much things from you. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the number value using Regex: (It's simple. Never be afraid of Regex)

```
Dim code as string = "<span>All Potatoes: 4</span>"
resultString = Regex.Match(code, @"\d+").Value
```